# Is there a way to trigger gesture events on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, events, multi-touch, gesture

I want to trigger multitouch gesture events on Mac OS X. Is there a way to do this? Mouse or keyboard events can be triggered with CGEventCreateMouseEvent and CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent. Is there similar low level function for multitouch events?

Rok

---

Your suggestion is not working. I've tried this code:
`- (void)rotateWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"ROTATE");
}
-(IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    CGEventSourceRef eventSource = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
    CGEventRef event = CGEventCreate(eventSource);
    CGEventSetType(event, NSEventTypeRotate);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event);
    NSLog(@"POST EVENT");
}`

But function rotateWithEvent never gets called. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this??? I am struggling with a similar problem a couple of days already, but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: did you find filed that is needed to be set?

Answer (score 3):

You could probably use `CGEventCreate` to create a gesture event. The event types "officially" defined for `CGEventCreate` don't include gesture event types, but you could pass in the values defined in `NSEvent.h`:

```
NSEventTypeGesture
NSEventTypeMagnify
NSEventTypeSwipe
NSEventTypeRotate
NSEventTypeBeginGesture
NSEventTypeEndGesture
```

The values for non-gesture types seem to map directly to the `kCGEvent<TYPE>` values in `CGEventTypes.h` so it's reasonable to expect the gesture event types will work:

```
CGEventSourceRef eventSource = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
CGEventRef event = CGEventCreate(eventSource);
CGEventSetType(event, NSEventTypeMagnify);
//continue to set up the event
```

Comment: could you give more details about what data to "set up" ?

Comment: how to set up this event

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you try posting a NSEventTypeBeginGesture before posting the rotate event?