# Is there a way to change rotation of gesture events?

Tags: macos, events, gesture, trackpad

I need to trigger gesture events in Mac OS X. I found this question:
[Is there a way to trigger gesture events on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487331/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-gesture-events-on-mac-os-x)
It works for me, but if I want to change rotation? For example,

```
- (void)rotateWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"ROTATE: %f", [event rotation]);
}
-(IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    ...
    CGEventSourceRef eventSource = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
    CGEventRef event = CGEventCreate(eventSource);
    CGEventSetType(event, NSEventTypeRotate);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event);
    ...
}
```

will log

```
ROTATE: 0.0
```

I was searching how to change rotation, but had not found anything...
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass the values for a CGEvent? Or what the event  field constants are for different kinds of gesture events? Or something completely different?

Comment: I am asking how to change magnification of NSEvent which would be passed through CGEvent. It doesn't matter how to do it. It will be great to change it through CGEvent fields.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this??? I am struggling with a similar problem a couple of days already, but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: Yeah I also consider how to set this (which?) fields to set rotation or magnification or swipe direction of this touch gestures

Comment: Maybe there could be possible to CGEventSetDoubleField(event, field_num,  15.0); and check field_num