# How can I synthesize Cocoa multi-touch gesture events?

Tags: cocoa, events, gesture, multi-touch

Dear stackoverflow folks! To this day I never saw the need to ask a question, because all of you have done a great job in asking and answering nearly all of the code-related problems I encountered. So, thank you for that!

At the moment I am working on an iOS application that is able to process raw touch events. These are then sent to an iMac over a WiFi network (the protocol I use is OSC). On the OS X side there is a server application listening for these OSC messages and converting them to mouse pointer movement / mouse button press / multi-touch gestures. So basically I want to build a (of course much more basic) software-bundle like mobile mouse (http://mobilemouse.com/) that I am able to adapt to the needs of our customers (by the means of customizing colors / additional buttons / gestures, and so on) for small remote control projects.

Right now, everything works but the multitouch gestures (pinch, rotate, two-finger-scroll). So my question is: **How can I programmatically create and post a multitouch gesture event?**

I searched a lot and found some threads about it here on stackoverflow, but none of them could help me:
[Is there a way to trigger gesture events on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487331/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-gesture-events-on-mac-os-x) - [Is there a way to change rotation of gesture events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799666/is-there-a-way-to-change-rotation-of-gesture-events?lq=1) - [Generate and post Multitouch-Events in OS X to control the mac using an external camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699165/generate-and-post-multitouch-events-in-os-x-to-control-the-mac-using-an-external?lq=1) - ...

Update 1:
The last thing I tried was:

```
CGEventSourceRef eventSource = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
CGEventRef event = CGEventCreate(eventSource);
CGEventSetType(event, NSEventTypeMagnify);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event);
CFRelease(eventSource);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you include what code you've tried so far but isn't working?

Comment: Thanks. Sure I can. Look at the update in the original post.