# Is there a way to trigger multi-gesture events on Mac OS X?

Tags: ios, macos, gesture

I want to trigger multitouch gesture events on Mac OS X. Is there a way to do this?

Mouse or keyboard events can be triggered with `CGEventCreateMouseEvent` and `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent`. Is there similar low level function for multitouch events?

like trigger something like four finger swipe up to open mission control.

I have tried like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487331/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-gesture-events-on-mac-os-x) but it doesn't work.

Comment: post your code what you have tried

Comment: thx~ just like the link~